# Average over list by row in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe with measurements stored as a list by row.

```
  Subject                 Measurements
1      s1  -0.4, -0.9, -1.1, -0.1,  0.1
2      s2  -1.4, -1.7, -1.7, -0.6, -1.7
3      s3  -1.0, -0.1, -0.6, -0.5, -0.1
4      s4  -0.2, -0.5, -0.2,  0.1, -0.7
5      s5   0.7,  0.2,  0.4,  0.7,  0.2
6      s6  -0.3, -0.1,  0.1, -0.2, -0.1
```

How do I average/find standard deviation/other list manipulations and add the output to a new column in data frame (e.g "mean")

**Edit**

Here's the data structure I'm working with:

```
structure(list(Subject = structure(1:6, .Label = c("s1", "s2", 
"s3", "s4", "s5", "s6"), class = "factor"), Measurements = list(
c(-0.4, -0.9, -1.1, -0.1, 0.1), c(-1.4, -1.7, -1.7, -0.6, 
-1.7), c(-1, -0.1, -0.6, -0.5, -0.1), c(-0.2, -0.5, -0.2, 
0.1, -0.7), c(0.7, 0.2, 0.4, 0.7, 0.2), c(-0.3, -0.1, 0.1, 
-0.2, -0.1))), .Names = c("Subject", "Measurements"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Well, the actual answer here is that you simply shouldn't organize your data that way. You should have multiple measurement columns, with NAs where appropriate. Once you reorganize your data, doing the calculations you want is trivial.

Comment: Can it split it from this form, or would I have to intervene at an earlier stage of reading in the data?

Comment: Yes, see my answer. The idiom I use there (`do.call` and `rbind`) could be used at an earlier stage as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you store your data more efficiently, this becomes much easier:

```
dat<- structure(list(Subject = structure(1:6, .Label = c("s1", "s2", 
"s3", "s4", "s5", "s6"), class = "factor"), Measurements = list(
c(-0.4, -0.9, -1.1, -0.1, 0.1), c(-1.4, -1.7, -1.7, -0.6, 
-1.7), c(-1, -0.1, -0.6, -0.5, -0.1), c(-0.2, -0.5, -0.2, 
0.1, -0.7), c(0.7, 0.2, 0.4, 0.7, 0.2), c(-0.3, -0.1, 0.1, 
-0.2, -0.1))), .Names = c("Subject", "Measurements"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

> dat <- data.frame(subject = dat$Subject,do.call(rbind,dat$Meas))
> dat$means <- apply(dat[,-1],1,mean)
> dat
  subject   X1   X2   X3   X4   X5 means
1      s1 -0.4 -0.9 -1.1 -0.1  0.1 -0.48
2      s2 -1.4 -1.7 -1.7 -0.6 -1.7 -1.42
3      s3 -1.0 -0.1 -0.6 -0.5 -0.1 -0.46
4      s4 -0.2 -0.5 -0.2  0.1 -0.7 -0.30
5      s5  0.7  0.2  0.4  0.7  0.2  0.44
6      s6 -0.3 -0.1  0.1 -0.2 -0.1 -0.12
```

Once you have each measurement in its own column, you can simply use `apply` (or `rowMeans`) os some similar function.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `Measurements` is a matrix within your `data.frame` (df).

```
df$means <- rowMeans(df$Measurements)
```

For a more general solution you can use apply with Margin = 1 for a given function.

```
df$SDs <- apply(df$Measurements, 1, sd)
```

If `Measurements` were actually a genuine `list` you'd use

```
df$SDs <- lapply(df$Measurements, sd)
```

That gives maximum performance but now your `SDs` column is a `list` so to make it a `vector` I'd go with...

```
df$SDs <- sapply(df$Measurements, sd)
```

(when I made a data.frame with a list included it didn't look like that so I didn't think it was really a list at first).

Comment: This doesn't work with the measurements. I've added the dput structure to the question so you can see what I'm working with. It says it is a list

Comment: @Amyunimus, the `sapply` method should work fine for your data.